# How to run PATCHMATCH source code

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I would like to inpaint one image with a corrupted part using the patches of another image. in the link below, the authors of PATCHMATCH algorithm has provided the users with the source code. PATCHMATCH algorithm tries to find the nearest patch in the second image to fill the corrupted patches in the first image.

main page of the paper with source code:
http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/index.php

and the link of source code:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/patchmatch-2.1.zip

My problem is that I followed the instruction in the readme.txt file and ran build_unix.sh in terminal of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,but got an error which says:

```
 Unknown MEX argument '-inline'.
 Unknown MEX argument '-inline'.
```

I removed -inline and execute the bash file in terminal and fortunately it worked and got this message:

```
MEX completed successfully.
MEX completed successfully.
```

Now my question is how to use this code to inpaint one image corrupted partially by using another image which comes from the same class (e.g.class)

For example:

[image: Palm Springs commercial photography]

[image: Palm Springs commercial photography]

I do really appreciate it if you could help me out of this problem. I am really in the need of help and have to make this source code run.
I will provide you with more information if needed.

Update: I have come up with an inpainting algorithm using Convolutional Neural Networks, which you can see the result below, I'd like to implement patchmatch algorithm to compare my result with this algorithm. CNN only gets corrupted image as input.

[image: Palm Springs commercial photography]

Comment: @MajidAzimi thanks alot for your comment. I have added the commands in the question

Comment: I downloaded the source code, but there's no nnmex_test.m!

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio as the mex compiler. I removed -inline and successfully compiled the project (with minor modification). Then I run test_mex.m which successfully calls the nnmex.mex64. basically you do not need the nnmex.m in this case. You can rename it to a random file name to make sure it is not being used. What you must have is the file nnmex.mex64

Comment: all the test files are working now. but how to put these two images into this code to inpain the first image is a good question!